# Two different configuration files share the same UUID. In configuration

Tags: eiffel

Don't understand this message and neither how to fix it under estudio 19.12

```
Warning code: VD80

Configuration warning

Two different configuration files share the same UUID. In configuration:
 /home/pg/data/solarity/sit-dev/eiffel/sit-platform/sit_platform_lib.ecf
the following reference:
 /opt/Eiffel_19.12/contrib/library/gobo/library/kernel/library.ecf
has the same UUID as the configuration file:
 /home/pg/data/solarity/sit-dev/eiffel/lib/thirdparty/gobo/library/kernel/src/library.ecf
referenced from:
 /home/pg/data/solarity/sit-dev/eiffel/lib/thirdparty/gobo/library/time/src/library.ecf.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the project `sit_platform_lib.ecf` (indirectly) references two different versions of Gobo kernel library:

- `/opt/Eiffel_19.12/contrib/library/gobo/`
- `/home/pg/data/solarity/sit-dev/eiffel/lib/thirdparty/gobo`

Whereas both could be identical copies, you need to select which one to use and update project settings to use only one version.